# How to build such query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need advice of MySQL genius.

Table1 '`objects`':

```
ID (int,key,autoincrement) | hash(text) | name(text)
```

Table2 '`logs`':

```
ID (int,key,autoincrement) | hash(text) | type(int) | time(text) | sum(int)
```

Table1 '`objects`' links with Table2 '`logs`' by column '`hash`'. That column contains MD5 values.

I need to get data with `type=1 or type=2` in such way for every object:

```
Name | sum all rows for this name and type=1 | sum all rows for this name and type=2
```

Tried queries like this

```
SELECT name, SUM(sum) as tsum 
FROM objects RIGHT JOIN logs using(hash) 
WHERE (type='1' OR type='2') 
GROUP BY type
```

But it forms data in format

```
Name | sum all rows for this name and type=1
Name | sum all rows for this name and type=2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` to get sum based on type 1/2 and use name column in group by

```
SELECT name,
SUM(case when type='1' then sum else 0 end) as firstsum ,
SUM(case when type='2' then sum else 0 end) as  secondsum
FROM objects 
RIGHT JOIN logs using(hash) 
WHERE (type='1' OR type='2') 
GROUP BY name
```